# UTF-8 not supported in environment variable?

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, properties

I'm using a Spring `@PropertySource` annotation to load a properties file according to an environment variable. (set in the `System variables` [of this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SAKE.jpg) in Windows)

I set `MY_APP = C:\Cliché`

And now my `@Configuration` class is also annotated with:

```
@PropertySource(value = "file:${MY_APP}/config/my.properties"
```

But Spring can't load the file because it seems to resolve the URL/path as: `C:\Clich,\config\my.properties`

Why ?

Answer (score 2):

Try, specify encoding in property source

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/myprop.properties", encoding="UTF-8")
```

And, you should set system encoding before you start the application

System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");

or via command line => `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: But these settings are for reading the **content** of the properties file right?

Comment: for @propertysource yes, 
but to interpret your system encoding you need set file.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: Neither ``encoding="UTF-8"`` as ``@PropertySource`` attribute, nor adding ``-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`` to my Tomcat VM arguments do work.
And as soon as I run a pure Java-config Spring application, there's nowhere I can set this ``System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");`` line to try...